# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username') at register

Tags: javascript, node.js

When i type the username which is there in Table "users" i am not facing any error but when i type wrong name that is the username which is not there in the table am facing error this is the error and code is attached below.

```
export const register = (req, res) => {
  //CHECK USER IF EXISTS

  const q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";

  const result = db.query(q, [req.body.username]);

  db.query(q, [req.body.username], (err, result, data) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
    if (data.length) return res.status(409).json("User already exists!");

    //CREATE A NEW USER
    //Hash the password
    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);

    const q =
      "INSERT INTO users (`username`,`email`,`password`,`name`) VALUE (?)";

    const values = [
      req.body.username,
      req.body.email,
      hashedPassword,
      req.body.name,
    ];

    db.query(q, [values], (err, data ) => {
      if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
      return res.status(200).json("User has been created.");
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: could you add a picture of the error, what line does it fail at as there are 2 references to the req.body.username

Comment: req.body is null not an empty array thats why .username "does not exist" add a null check on hashedPassword

Comment: Why are you calling `db.query()` twice with the samq query?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator He shouldn't even be getting to the `hashedPassword` code, since it should fail when doing the first query.

Comment: Not related to the error, but `VALUE (?)` should be `VALUES (?)`

Comment: @Barmar the code can be refactored but it skips the first two returns if there are no errors and the returned length is greater than 0. Else it continues with the code below, so yes the hashed password is hit.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator But it's crashing at `const result = db.query(q, [req.body.username]);` because `req.body` is undefined.

Comment: Have you loaded the bodyparser middleware?

Comment: @Barmar check my first comment, we are on the same page.

Comment: You say "req.body is null". The error message says it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `data.length` for `result.length`, data has some information about the execution, so it will always be truthy:

```
db.query(q, [req.body.username], (err, result) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);
        if (result.length) return res.status(409).json("User already exists!");  //change to result
```

Also you can remove this line, it's not being used

```
  const result = db.query(q, [req.body.username]);
```